# How To Insert Many To Many Tabel Auto Increment

Tags: php, mysql

```
A                 B                 C
-------         ---------         ------------
id_A*           id_B*              id_C*
name            id_A**             name
address         id_C**
```

I created a table as in the example above I've tried to do input in Table A, B then C, but what if I want to do the input of C then the input table B in conjunction with Table A, all tables in the auto increment primary key

```
            <input type="text" name="id_A" />
        <input type="text" name="id_B" />
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="text" name="address" />
        <select class="form-control" name="id_C">
                <?php
                    $query  = "select * from C";
                    $r      = mysql_query($query);
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)) {

                ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id_C'];?>" name="id_C"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
        </select>
```

And Then

```
            isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $id_A               = $_POST['id_A'];
        $name               = $_POST['name'];
        $address            = $_POST['address'];

        $q      = "insert into A (id_A,name,address) VALUES('$id_A','$name','$address')";
        $dq     = mysql_query($q);
        $id_B   = $_POST['id_B'];

            $query = mysql_query("insert into B(id_b,id_A,id_C) values('$id_b', '$id_A' ,'$id_C')");
```

please help me,
i' am a realy2 confuse

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I never have the auto-increment id column mentioned in an insert statement. imo, That is an excellent way of confusing you and the database engine. i.e.Let the database look after the id's. So the issue then becomes how to link up the records. One way, insert C and store the id (`last_insert_id`). Insert A and store the id, Use whatever order you want  to insert the A and C records As it is only B that needs the id's of the other records.